# large text as parameter in javascript function

Tags: javascript, string

I would like to process large amount of text inside javascript, I tried to feed the text as a parameter to my js function

```
function processText(myText){

     //do some task
}
```

It seems that javascript cannot pass the parameter correctly.

Is there any work around for this problem?

Comment: That's strange. Can you split the input string up into manageable bits, and handle them separately?

Comment: You need to add some more information to your question - what are you passing ? what "large amount of text"? what error message ?

Comment: Can you provide some details? Can you find the exact error/exception, using Firebug or similar js debugger? Are you sure that it works with any input?

Comment: I am using IOS and UIWebView, the text is to be paginated in a div and then returned back. I will not use the devise, it will run on the iOS simulator.

Answer (score 0):

in the main code call processText function like:

```
$yourText=urlencode($originalText); 
processText($yourText);
```

above is php code sample

```
function processText(myText) {  
    var lsRegExp = /\+/g
    var properText=unescape(String(myText).replace(lsRegExp, " "));
// do something with properText
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using IOS and UIWebView to prerender a book.